# Passing variable from a function to another function

Tags: python

I wish to ask that I want to take data and data2 from number() and transfer it to take() in which I can use it to print at the main method

```
def number():
    global data
    data=1
    global data2
    data2=2
    
def take():
    global finalAns
    finalAns=data+data2
    
print(finalAns)
```

After writing the code, the error I obtained is

```
NameError: name 'finalAns' is not defined
```

Why is this so? I thought that all variable that has a global attribute can be passed to other methods.

Comment: you first need to execute the number() and take() functions

Comment: Using global variables isn't a good habit, consider using return in your function instead, in your example you need to call `number()` then `take()`, else `finalAns` isn't defined

Answer (score 3):

Don't use globals.  (There are ways you can do this, but don't.)

```
def number():
    data = 1
    data2 = 2
    return data1, data2
    
def take(data1, data2):
    finalAns = data + data2
    return finalAns
    
print(take(*number())  # 3
```

Or:

```
data1, data2 = number()
finalAns = take(data1, data2)
print(finalAns)
```

Any information that you want to get *from* a function should be `return`ed by it.  Any information that you want to give *to* a function should be a parameter.  The caller isn't required to use the same names for the arguments or the return values that are used inside the function:

```
x, y = number()  # x, y = 1, 2
z = take(x, y)   # z = 3
print(finalAns)
```

Comment: Albeit correct, the use of * might be confusing if the OP is new to python. Maybe it would be more clear to also include a more traditional approach, storing the result of number in two variables and call take passing two parameters.